# Firebase user privacy

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking into using Firebase in an iOS app. Functionally it looks good, but is there any way to ensure that user data is kept private **from the developer**?

I know that I can require authentication and ensure that users only see their own data in the app. I also know that it uses HTTPS. My concern is that when I log in to the Firebase console, **I can see everything**. I want to be able to honestly say to users that their private data is actually private, not just from other users but from me and any other developers who work on the project in the future.

I don't need encryption, necessarily, but if that's the only option then I'd consider it. But I also don't think that "private" data is actually private if anyone who works on the app could browse through it whenever they like.

Comment: Firebase is running on a secure HTTP, but for me personally I added encryption as well since an app I'm doing contains sensitive information. It provides me with an additional security layer (though not necessarily needed), but can safely say to users that their data aren't compromised.

Comment: @adjuremods Thanks. I'm not enough of a crypto expert that I could promise secure encryption, but it would at least guarantee that I couldn't see user data.

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm on the Firebase dev team.  I'm @eob on Twitter.  If you DM your e-mail address there I'd love to discuss this idea.